# How can I solve QML "Text is not a type" error?

Tags: qt, qml

I'm following [wireframe Qml example in QtCreator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-wireframe-example.html)

I want to add a title to the view, so I add a Text component in main.qml.

```
/****************************************************************************/

import QtQuick 2.1 as QQ2
import Qt3D.Core 2.0
import Qt3D.Render 2.0
import Qt3D.Input 2.0
import Qt3D.Extras 2.0

Entity {
    id: root

    // Render from the mainCamera
    components: [
        RenderSettings {
            activeFrameGraph: ForwardRenderer {
                id: renderer
                camera: mainCamera
            }
        },
        // Event Source will be set by the Qt3DQuickWindow
        InputSettings { }
    ]

    BasicCamera {
        id: mainCamera
        position: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, 15.0 )
    }

    FirstPersonCameraController { camera: mainCamera }

    WireframeMaterial {
        id: wireframeMaterial
        effect: WireframeEffect {}
        ambient: Qt.rgba( 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 )
        diffuse: Qt.rgba( 0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 )

        QQ2.SequentialAnimation {
            loops: QQ2.Animation.Infinite
            running: true

            QQ2.NumberAnimation {
                target: wireframeMaterial;
                property: "lineWidth";
                duration: 1000;
                from: 0.8
                to: 1.8
            }

            QQ2.NumberAnimation {
                target: wireframeMaterial;
                property: "lineWidth";
                duration: 1000;
                from: 1.8
                to: 0.8
            }

            QQ2.PauseAnimation { duration: 1500 }
        }
    }

    TrefoilKnot {
        id: trefoilKnot
        material: wireframeMaterial
    }

    Text {
        id: name
        text: qsTr("TrefoilKnot")
    }


}
```

But when I run the app, Qt give me

**qrc:/main.qml:114:5: Text is not a type**

error

Text is just a basic Qt Quick QML Type, I dont't know why is that happened.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import QtQuick 2.1 as QQ2
...
```

You have imported QtQuick as QQ2 so you need to refer to `Text` as `QQ2.Text`, ie.

```
QQ2.Text {
    id: name
    text: qsTr("TrefoilKnot")
}
```